# Compiling Error: Not a Statement

Tags: java, netbeans

I am working on a text-based RPG and came across this error while working on it.

```java
package game;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

/**
 *
 * @author Pyro
 */
public class SpriteSheetLoader {
    public int[] sheetPixels;
    public int[] pixels;
    int x, y, sheetWidth;

    public SpriteSheetLoader(BufferedImage sheet){
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(sheet.getWidth(), sheet.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        image.getGraphics().drawImage(sheet, 0, 0, null);

        sheetPixels = ((DataBufferInt)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        sheetWidth = sheet.getWidth();

    }

    public void grabTile(int tile, int width, int height) {
        sheetPixels = new int[width * height];

        int xTile = tile % 16;
        int yTile = tile % 16;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                int value = pixels[(x + (y * width))] * sheetPixels[((x + (xTile * width)) + (y + (yTile * height)) * sheetWidth)];  
            }
        }
    }



}
```

The error showed up around the 7th line and I can't seem to figure out the problem

Comment: What is the error that is showing up? I don't see `sheetPixels`, `pixels`, or `sheetWidth` defined in the scope of this snippet so I can't tell you if any of those are the problem.

Comment: It is saying that the seventh line is not a statement

Comment: There is no assignment on that line.  It looks like you are just calculating a value.

Comment: i added the rest of the code into the question

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any assignment with your code:

```
pixels[(x + (y * width))] * sheetPixels[((x + (xTile * width)) + (y + (yTile * height)) * sheetWidth)];
```

You need to do something with the value here, I'm not sure what you are trying to do (like maybe set the value in the array or something) so here is just an example.

```
int value = pixels[(x + (y * width))] * sheetPixels[((x + (xTile * width)) + (y + (yTile * height)) * sheetWidth)];
```

In addition to your error, you do `sheetPixels = new int[width * height];` and immediately after try to get data out of the array with `sheetPixels[...]`, but that is a whole different problem than the one you asked.